# Question about rational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic

Does each rational number have an integer when you multiply it by the whole number you get an integer?

In other words, is the following implication always true?

$$(q,n)\ \ q\in\Bbb Q, \ n,a\in\Bbb N \Rightarrow q\cdot n=a$$

thanks.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Yes, as long as the rational number is positive (otherwise, $\Bbb N$ is not enough - you have to go to $\Bbb Z$).

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the text: yes, that's how you define the rationals.

---

Answer to the "equation": 
No, take $-1\in\Bbb Q$. There exist no $n,a\in\Bbb N$ such that $-1\cdot n=-n=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. By definition, a rational number $r$ is such that there exists integers $q,p$ such that $r = \frac{p}{q}$, so the integer in question is $q$.

Comment: Now, the equation you posted, and the sentence you wrote, are inconsistent. Are we talking about integers or natural numbers?

Comment: sorry i mean to Z set(integers)